# How can I increase my samsung galaxy s4 signal power

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, network-signal

I'm having poor signal quality from service provider(the signal for recieving calls, messages etc.)

When I check from "about device" section, it usually says around -110 dbm and 2 asu.

I have no problems connecting internet via wifi( my home's modem, not mobile data)

I have given the phone to a technician for repair but it's still not fixed.

I opened the case and checked antenna(which I'm guessing, was replaced by the technician, so it's most probably pretty new), which looked like okay.

I usually recive only 1-2 bars and rarely 4 bars of signal quality.

What might be the reason(s)?

Comment: Distance and obstructions from the nearest cell tower? I cannot get even that inside my house, and have to make calls from the driveway. Service to the HOME is generally NOT GUARANTEED by your service provider, just to your AREA. Check your contract wording.

Comment: I've been using the same places for the last 5 years, this problem started to occur a month ago, so that's not because of the area I'm in.